# Concatenating iterable of defaultdicts into DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, defaultdict

Simplified example of what I have now:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d1 = defaultdict(list)
d2 = defaultdict(list)

d1['a'] = [1, 2, 3]
d1['b'] = [True, True, True]

d2['a'] = [4, 5 , 6]
d2['b'] = [False, False, False]
```

Desired result:

```
   a      b
0  1   True
1  2   True
2  3   True
3  4  False
4  5  False
5  6  False
```

This line below will work, but I'm looking for an alternative that doesn't have to instantiate a separate DataFrame for every defaultdict.

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d) for d in (d1, d2)]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Could also start with:

```
pd.DataFrame([d1, d2])
```

and convert that to long format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could merge the `dicts` and *then* instantiate your dataframe.

```
d3 = {k : d1[k] + d2[k] for k in d1}
d3
{'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'b': [True, True, True, False, False, False]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d3)
df
   a      b
0  1   True
1  2   True
2  3   True
3  4  False
4  5  False
5  6  False
```

---

Automating the merge for multiple objects:

```
d3 = defaultdict(list)
for d in dict_list:
    for k in d:
        d3[k].extend(d[k])

df = pd.DataFrame(d3)
```

Answer (score 1):

By using your `pd.concat`

```
pd.DataFrame([d1, d2]).stack().apply(pd.Series).unstack(-2).\
    T.sort_index(level=1).reset_index(drop=True)

Out[648]: 
   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  1
2  3  1
3  4  0
4  5  0
5  6  0
```